# Check data and disable previous record if change occurred and insert new

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a ssis package that will fetch files from a specific location on adhoc basis since frequency of files is not fixed and we have to check file daily and if files are available then load the data in table.

I have created the ssis package where I will fetch the file and load the same in staging table that part is done now.

I need your help in following scenario where from staging table I have to load data in maintbl structure as follows:

```
DECLARE @maintbl TABLE 
( 
   id             INT IDENTITY, 
   code           VARCHAR(10), 
   NAME           VARCHAR(100), 
   countrylocated VARCHAR(10), 
   validfrom      DATE, 
   validto        DATE 
)
```

I wanted to create a procedure and will call that procedure after loading the data in staging inside the ssis package.

The scenario is as follows:

- record in file as of 2019-04-10
- 2019-04-01, ax,auxy,ch
- values should be inserted in table @maintbl

Table:

```
  code   name   countrylocated    validfrom      validto   
 -------------------------------------------------------------
  ax     auxy    ch               2019-04-01     9999-12-31
```

Record in file as of 2019-04-16 (there is no change in data on date is change )

```
2019-04-15, ax,auxy,ch
```

No values should be inserted in table `@maintbl` and no update either

```
 code   name   countrylocated    validfrom      validto   
-----------------------------------------------------------
 ax     auxy    ch               2019-04-01     9999-12-31
```

Record in file as of 2019-06-20 (there is no change in data on date is change )

```
2019-06-19, ax,auxy,IN
```

the old record with same exchange code should be closed as of 2019-06-18 and a new record should be inserted with 2019-06-19 till  9999-12-31

```
 code   name   countrylocated    validfrom      validto   
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 ax     auxy    ch               2019-04-01     2019-06-18
 ax     auxy    IN               2019-06-19     9999-12-31
```

Column code is column to check the record

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Search for SCD2 (Slowly Changing Dimension 2) - And this will give you some merge scripts you should implement to make this feature.

Comment: my question is: I wanted to write a stored proc that will check the staging table and insert or update records as per rule mentioned.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Can you have multiple "changes" to the same `code`+`name` in one file?